# DataGrid Data Binding Issue with Styles

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid and I want to apply text wrapping to all the cells, so I've defined this style:

```
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="95" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}" Width="95"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding Category}" Width="95" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

and I set my DataGrid's ItemsSource in my code behind like this:

```
        myDataGrid.ItemsSource= new Customers[] 
        { 
                new ComputerStandard{Name="Michael Thomas",Address="16 Greenville Avenue",Category="A"},            
                new ComputerStandard{Name="Fiona Thompson",Address="19 Wright Street",Category="F"},            
                new ComputerStandard{Name="Jack Smith",Address="133 Kensington Road",Category="B"},
                new ComputerStandard{Name="Michael jackson",Address="11 Wine Street",Category="C"},
                new ComputerStandard{Name="Jerry Holmes",Address="10 Awson Street",Category="G"},
                new ComputerStandard{Name="David Philips",Address="Not Specified",Category="A"}
        };
```

But somewhere something fails with my binding expression that I set in my style `Text="{Binding}"` and I end up with:

[image]

Obviously the binding expression `Text="{Binding}"` is failing, I know this because when I remove the style everything works perfectly. How do I go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `DataGridColumn.Binding` property does not set the `DataContext` for each `DataGridCell`. The `DataContext` is still equal to the entire Row's `DataContext`

Switch from binding the `ContentTemplate`, to binding the `Template`, and then you have access to the `ContentPresenter`

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="15" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

            </TextBlock>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help :

```
<Style x:Key="MyGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">    
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
               <Border x:Name="MyBorder" >
                  <TextBlock Background="Transparent" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                     TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Height="auto" Width="auto"> 
                   <ContentPresenter 
                     Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" 
                     ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"/>
                  </TextBlock>
               </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/a14292e9-0150-42dd-8a7c-5be9deddf421).